# Manual screen rotate via terminal isn't working

Tags: auto-rotation

I want to fix the custom ROM (android 7.1.1 Resurrection Remix) issue on my tab TB2-X30L (portrait orientation instead of landscape on startup), but when I write the command `content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:1`, the screen doesn't rotate (on my phone with android 9, sm-j600f, this command is working).

Autorotation is working. Root access and TWRP are present.

Any way to rotate the screen via terminal?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and give more details on on the two devices you mention? At least the Android version would be good to know and the device model would be good, too. As you are running custom ROM the used ROM way also have an influence on your problem.

Comment: Have you actually ascertained that your custom ROM is using the same key "user_rotation" and expect the same value you are supplying to act on rotation? It is best if you toggle auto-rotation through quick settings and watch what changes it make to a Settings' key, using logcat.